# Elegant way in Python to map string content to method calls

Tags: python

Given this example code where we have a series of log processors, I can't help feeling there ought to be a more pythonic/efficient way of deciding which log processor to use to process some data:

```
class Component1ErrorLogProcessor:
    def process(logToProcess):
    
        # Do something with the logs
        pass
        
class Component2ErrorLogProcessor:
    def process(logToProcess):
    
        # Do something with the logs
        pass
        

class LogProcessor:

    def __init__(self):
        self.component1 = Component1ErrorLogProcessor()
        self.component2 = Component2ErrorLogProcessor()

    def process_line(self, line, component):
        if component == "Component1Log-" or component == "[Component1]":
            self.component1.process_errors(line)
        elif component == "Component2Log-" or component == "[Component2]":
            self.component2.process_errors(line)
```

Comment: You could use a dictionary where the keys are "Component1Log-", "[Component1]" etc and their associated values are instances of the appropriate class

Comment: This is more of a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use the idea of registry, so you map each class to component names.

There are a bunch of different ways to go about this, here's a quick example by using a base class:

```
class ComponentLogProcessor(object):
    _Mapping = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, *component_names):
        for name in component_names:
            cls._Mapping[name] = cls
    
    @classmethod
    def cls_from_component(cls, component):
        return cls._Mapping[component]


class Component1ErrorLogProcessor(ComponentLogProcessor):
    def process(logToProcess):

        # Do something with the logs
        pass
Component1ErrorLogProcessor.register('Component1Log-', '[Component1]')

class Component2ErrorLogProcessor(ComponentLogProcessor):
    def process(logToProcess):

        # Do something with the logs
        pass
Component2ErrorLogProcessor.register('Component2Log-', '[Component2]')


class LogProcessor:

    def process_line(self, line, component):
        ComponentLogProcessor.cls_from_component(component).process_errors(line)
```